# VSCode insist on suggesting entryComponents for Angular2 app

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

Developing an angular 2 app in VSCode and I've been confounded by a certain behavior of VSCode.  When typing something like the following:

`@Component({
   ...
   templateUrl: './home.component'
}`

VSCode wants to suggest `entryComponents` while I'm typing `.component`

This is frustrating because I must always hit the ESC key to keep it from changing from component to entryComponents.

I have tried removing all of my extensions and that doesn't help.  Is there anyway to stop this?  Where would VSCode get that particular code completion suggestion?

updates:  I tried this with double quotes and it still happens.  Also, it only happens if I begin with a dot in front of components.

Comment: It's odd that it would do that since you're in the middle of a string at that point. Maybe it isn't recognizing single quotes as string delimiters? Try double quotes. See if there is an option to include single quotes.

Comment: It does it with double quotes as well :(

Comment: I'd suggest that this is a bug but they had a similar complaint about autocomplete in comments and that ended up being closed without really fixing the issue. Maybe post an issue for it over in the GitHub repository's [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues).

Comment: My bad on the example I provided.  It happens when I'm in the @Component constructor where, as it turns out, there is an argument for "entryComponents".  Would be nice if it didn't suggest it when in quotes.